# Dynamically select a custom class using a string value and instantiate

Tags: swift, bundle

I plan to use a string value to select a custom defined class. The desired class object is returned using `Bundle.main.classNamed`.

For better understanding what I want to do, here is a short code example with some custom classes:

```swift
class Product: NSObject {
  var name: String

  init(_ name: String) {
    self.name = name
  }
}

class Apple: Product {
  var num: Int

  init(_ num: Int) {
    self.num = num
    super .init("Apple")
  }
}

class Melon: Product {
  var num: Int
  var size: Int

  init(_ num: Int, _ size: Int) {
    self.num = num
    self.size = size
    super .init("Melon")
  }
}
```

The class `Apple` and `Melon` are subclasses of `Product`, each with its own initialization method. Given a string value like `"1000 Apples"` I want to instantiate an `Apple` class. To get the desired class I use `Bundle.main.classNamed` like this:

```swift
let clsName: String = "Apple"

let nameSpace = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleExecutable"] as! String
let loadedClass = Bundle.main.classNamed(nameSpace + "." + "Apple") as! NSObject.Type
```

How do I instantiate `loadedClass`?

```swift
let apple = loadedClass.init(100)
```

Gives an `Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init()' for class 'MyApp.Apple'`

```swift
let unknownFruit = loadedClass(100)
```

Gives the Error: `Initializing from a metatype value must reference 'init' explicitly`

While there are two subclasses with two different initialization methods it should be possible to use `loadedClass` with its own `init` method, but this doesn't work so far.

---

Swift 5.2.4
Xcode 11.5

Comment: You are casting class as `NSObject`, which of course doesn't have an `init(Int)`. Hence it fails.

Actually you have a deeper problem: your sub-classes have **different constructors**, so you kind of have to have a switch here, where for different types of data you invoke different constructors. What you can do is case to `Product` instead of `NSObject`, and get product to support various parameters. Or have several sub-classes of product, each depends on arguments it accepts, and then cast that way.

Comment: Also I think there's a core problem with your design: doesn't look like your class per product is justified... Hard to say what exactly you need in this case without seeing more code, but I will post one suggestion as an answer below (it won't fit the comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comments under the question to get a context for this answer. But I wonder if you are solving a wrong problem, and it would be better for you to switch to a different design. For example without knowing how your product classes are used, I think it may be a good case for enum:

```
enum Product {

    case apple(num: Int)
    case melon(num: Int, size: Int)

    init?(_ name: String, _ num: Int = 0, _ size: Int = 0) {
        switch name.lowercased() {
        case "apple":
            self = .apple(num: num)
        case "melon":
            self = .melon(num: num, size: size)
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}

extension Product: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .apple(let num):
            return "apple(\(num))"
        case .melon(let num, let size):
            return "melon(\(num) - \(size)"
        }
    }
}

let clsName: String = "Apple"
let apple = Product(clsName, 100)
print("I am \(apple?.description)") // apple(100)
```

Anyway, this is more a food for thought, which was too long for comment! Feel free to delete.

Comment: Thank you for response. That is not what I wanted but it helps me. The example above is kept very simple to breakdown the problem I was working on.